# Automatic software updates from a local SVN repository

Tags: linux, svn, cron, auto-update

I need to create a cron job on my Linux machine to automatically check for new versions of some system-critical software that is maintained via Subversion. I already did the checkout so now I'd just need to update the local copy of the source code and build from the latest versions periodically with a cron script.

Hence is the question, is there an easy way of determining whether a new version of the software has appeared in the local repository, probably having the option of choosing to look into either `branches` or `tags` subdirectory, *as well as* getting the path to the subdirectory with the latest version (within either `branches` or `tags`), maybe also applying a custom keyword, for example, "secur" to filter out any non-security updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a script which calls `svn info` and parses out the revision and/or timestamps to determine if there has been an update. Example output:

```
$ svn info http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/readme.doc
Path: readme.doc
Name: readme.doc
URL: http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/readme.doc
Repository Root: http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test
Repository UUID: 5e7d134a-54fb-0310-bd04-b611643e5c25
Revision: 1
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: sally
Last Changed Rev: 42
Last Changed Date: 2003-01-14 23:21:19 -0600 (Tue, 14 Jan 2003)
Lock Token: opaquelocktoken:14011d4b-54fb-0310-8541-dbd16bd471b2
Lock Owner: harry
Lock Created: 2003-01-15 17:35:12 -0600 (Wed, 15 Jan 2003)
Lock Comment (1 line):
My test lock comment
```

You could easily include a branch/tag in the URL, and use the `-R` switch to get a list of paths underneath those. From there, you could loop through the first-level paths and check the revision of each to determine if there's a new one. Notice the output contains comments, last changed timestamp, revision and node kind; that should be everything you need to get your script working.

Comment: And it's up to the script to qualify a path as a first-level one or there is a switch for that? It simply takes too long for svn to loop through _all_ the directories..

Comment: There's no separate switch that I know of, the script would have to qualify it (shouldn't be too hard to count the number of slashes in the path)

Answer (score 1):

- If "... in local repository..." means "in Subversion server, which I can manage and configure", then:

  - write post-commit hook, which will see at changes in /tags|/branches (`svnlook dirs-changed REPO-PATH`, f.e) and run some actions, if needed
- If you have only ordinary remote-access to repo, you can:

  - have latest tag (?) in working copy
  - check log of repository /tags in cron (or by demand)

After it you have parse results of `svn info` and `svn log -q REPO-URL/tags/ -v -l 1` and detect appearing of new tag, which you switch|relocate+update or mkdir+checkout

**Sample:**

Tag 1.0

```
>svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: Z:\1.0
URL: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/tags/1.0
Repository Root: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello
Repository UUID: 65c3f143-cc60-1d4e-9546-1f0378d96c08
Revision: 34
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: lazybadger
Last Changed Rev: 11
Last Changed Date: 2010-07-17 04:45:05 +0600 (Сб, 17 июл 2010)
```

Log

```
>svn log -q http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/tags/ -v -l 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r22 | lazybadger | 2010-07-17 05:31:00 +0600 (Сб, 17 июл 2010)
Changed paths:
   A /tags/1.1 (from /trunk:21)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or XML-version

```
>svn log -q http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/tags/ -v -l 1 --xml --incremental
<logentry
   revision="22">
<author>lazybadger</author>
<date>2010-07-16T23:31:00.513125Z</date>
<paths>
<path
   text-mods="false"
   kind="dir"
   copyfrom-path="/trunk"
   copyfrom-rev="21"
   action="A"
   prop-mods="true">/tags/1.1</path>
</paths>
</logentry>
```

in any case, extract revision number from log, and if it's more than revision of WC ("Last Changed Rev"): we have to have new version. URL is Repository Root+(path value from XML log | parsed line with /tags from text-log)